# Default Qemu settings for runqemu command

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, qemu, bitbake, openembedded

Is it possible to set default Qemu settings (like cpu, memory, etc) that can be used by runqemu script?

I know that there is a runtime parameter `qemuparams=<xyz>`, but it has to be explicitly provided each time. I am looking for a permanent setting that changes default values even when the project is re-compiled with bitbake.

Comment: You can change these values in runqemu script.